# Laravel Collection - put specific item on last position

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, laravel-collection

I have database table with different roles and I need collection where items with role `owner` will be last. Here is database example:

| ID | Role |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | admin |
| 2 | user |
| 3 | user |
| 4 | owner |
| 5 | user |

How can I sort collection with those data to get item with role `owner` as last? I could only think of sorting it alphabetically, saving to some variable and deleting the record with the owner role from the collection, and then pasting it into the collection as last. But it seems unnecessarily complicated to me, isn't there an easier way?

The reason why I need this is because I need remove all selected users and to be sure that user/owner is the last one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You Can Use Conditional rendering. For That you need to use `DB::raw`
Example:

```php
Model::select('id', 'role')
  ->orderBy(DB::raw('role = "owner"'), 'ASC');
```

Or you can use shortcut `orderByRaw`

```php
Model::select('id', 'role')->orderByRaw("role = 'owner' ASC");
```

It will place `owners` At the end.

Check Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d2b64/2

Comment: Great, I didn't think about ordering by specific role. Thank you, btw I used the same but with edit `->orderByRaw('role = "owner" ASC')`

Comment: Cool, I'm glad you helped

Answer (score 1):

For eloquent, you can use `sortBy()` method with `array_search()` :

```
$collection = Model::get();

$data = $collection->sortBy(function($item){
    return array_search($item->role, ['admin', 'user', 'owner']);
});
```

Comment: What if Model has hundreds of records? First you select and then sort? I think this is not good solution.

Comment: @Malkhazi I think you need to ask this on laravel's developer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby

Comment: It's clear that `sortBy` method exists and I use it a lot. But it's not recomended to use in this case, when you can sort data using `SQL`. Collections are heavy, especially when you are blindly using `get` or `all` method.

Comment: Result will be right but I agree with @Malkhazi - in my case I can have thousands of records and fetching all records could be pain but I admit that I didn't wrote it into description.